# Поиск повторяющихся строк в файле

Tags: linux, консоль, macos

Есть файл subsum2.txt. В нем нужно найти повторяющиеся строки и вывести их количество (сколько раз они повторяются) с помощью терминала MacOS (похож на линукс)

Пробовала так: `cat subsum2.txt | sort | uniq -c`   
Выводятся повторяющиеся строки, но не пишется количество их повторений, перед каждой строкой просто стоит цифра 1, а дальше они повторяются и каждый раз стоит 1, вручную считать долго.

Пробовала так: `cat subsum2.txt | sort | uniq -c -d`
Выводится строка
`usage: uniq [-c | -d | -u] [-i] [-f fields] [-s chars] [input [output]]`
и все, ничего не происходит.

Comment: странно, под linux команда `cat subsum2.txt | sort | uniq -c -d` нормально отрабатывает и делает то что вам нужно. Возможно там какая-то проблема с кодировкой самого файла. Попробуйте выполнить в консоли команду: `echo -e "aa\nbb\ncc\nbb\naa\naa" |sort |uniq -c -d`

Comment: Тоже выводит usage: uniq [-c | -d | -u] [-i] [-f fields] [-s chars] [input [output]]

Comment: значит в утилите `uniq` под **macOS** есть какие-то свои ограничения и/или специфика использования. При желании можно переписать на `awk`, как пример: `... |sort | awk '{if($0==x)n++;else {print n,x;n=1}}{x=$0}END{print n,x}' |awk 'FNR>1 && $1 != 1'`

Answer (score 0):

Получилось командой sort subsum2.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr